# Split an AWS GraphQL API Schema into multiple files

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-cdk

Currently I develop an GraphQL API via CDK on AWS.
So I write the `schema.graphql` locally and deploy afterwards via `cdk deploy` to an AWS Instance.

My Schema-File has now 600 LOC without code/documentation comments. I try to find a way to split this one file into multiple files for better maintenance. Does anyone has a solution or hint for this situation I am in.

The [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/designing-your-schema.html) does not mention anything for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using codebuild in some fashion, you could have one of the build steps be to build a unified file out of a collection of files.

So have a folder like

```
schema/part-a.js
schema/part-b.js
```

```
// part-a.js
function a () {
  return `
    some part of the schema
  `
```

(Do this for each part of the schema you subdivide)

Then have a main script which imports all of the `part-*.js` files and calls their function to combine them into a single string. THEN

```
import { a } from 'part-a.js'
...

const bigTemplateString = `${a}${b}${c}...`

await fs.writeFile(bigTemplateString, 'schema.graphql')
```